# How can I modify the font of category labels in a radar chart in Microsoft Report Builder?

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have added a radar chart to an rdl file in Microsoft Report Builder. I want to modify the font of the category group labels, but I don't see a property for that. Normally I can select the thing I want to modify and then find Properties in the right-click menu, but I can't select the category labels.

Is there an alternative? If I open the rdl in Notepad++, I can see the XML. Is there a tag I could add there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These Label properties are kind of hidden. To make matters worse, default font values aren't in the XML as FontFamily to find and fix.

```
        <ChartAreas>
          <ChartArea Name="Default">
            <ChartCategoryAxes>
              <ChartAxis Name="Primary">
                <Style>
                  <Border>
                    <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                    <Style>None</Style>
                  </Border>
                  <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                  <Color>#5c5c5c</Color>
                </Style>
```

Highlight the Radar Chart.

In the Properties window, click on the Chart Areas ellipsis (`...`). (1)

In the Chart Area Collection Editor, click on the Category Axes ellipsis. (2)

The properties for the Category are in the Labels properties. (3)

After you save the changes, the XML will be added (`<FontFamily>Arial Black</FontFamily>`).

```
        <ChartAreas>
          <ChartArea Name="Default">
            <ChartCategoryAxes>
              <ChartAxis Name="Primary">
                <Style>
                  <Border>
                    <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                    <Style>None</Style>
                  </Border>
                  <FontFamily>Arial Black</FontFamily>
                  <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                  <Color>#5c5c5c</Color>
                </Style>
```

[image]